# Как настроить разрешенные IP адреса и подсети к модулю в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Как настроить разрешенные IP адреса  и подсети к модулю в Yii2?

Прочитал в справочнике что за это отвечает специальный параметр:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-debug-module.html#$allowedIPs-detail

```
public array $allowedIPs = ['127.0.0.1', '::1']
```

Но как правильно его настроить и почему в этом параметре указан Ip адрес с `'::1'`? Что что такое - `::1`?

Comment: ::1 это localhost в IPv6

Answer (score 1):

Для доступа с определенных IP просто перечислите их через запятую. Для указания подсетей используйте *.